# BxSlider Fade in and Out

Tags: jquery, css, slider, bxslider

StackOverflow'ers

I am new to jQuery but I am currently using the BXslider Plug in.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').bxSlider();
  });
</script>
```

All I want to do is to make the slider, on each slide, slide in and out, left-to-right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the link you posted are all your options to customize the plugin. You can change the values like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    });
});
```

If you are looking for more transition/easing options, you will need to include jQuery Easing. Get that here: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Then add the easing option like this:

```
easing: 'swing',
```

FYI 'swing' is the default.

Comment: Just what i was after! However it is not 'swinging' in. It is just fading from one slide to the next, so its lost its default left-to-right transition. 

Any chance on making it come in from right to left and fade in?

But thank you very much for your btw.

Comment: If you don't want it to fade, remove the mode option (since the default is 'horizontal'). To change the direction of the slider, add this option: autoDirection: 'prev',

Comment: I want it to slide horizontally and fade. At the moment it is just fading. Any ideas?

Comment: Like I said, change the mode to something else besides 'fade'. The thing is, I don't think you can really have it fade and slide... do you have an example of this action?

Comment: If i change the mode it generally is one or the other, might try easein, to see how that flows.

Thank you Connor! Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The ID of your list or div has to be equal to what is the jQuery code.

See if there are other codes that were not properly closed and that might be interfering with this.

Make sure added the version of jQuery that is compatible with the plugin and added the .min.js in the page header.

Comment: I have done all that, I only listed the part of the jQuery that needs to change. The Slider is working fine so I have no need to check the above, I just cannot work out a way to add each slide to fade..